# Android gradle always run version 7.4-rc-1

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, sonarqube

I'm working on SonarQube; a project scanning tool. I define SonarQube properties in *build.gradle*. Everything works fine. I can scan my project and the result is updated in the server normally.

The problem is the gradle version used to run *sonarqube* task. On the first *sonarqube* run with the command `gradle sonar`, it always failed with error

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.5. Current version is 7.4-rc-1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users...\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-7.5-all.zip

[image: gradle error : Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.5. Current version is 7.4-rc-1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users...\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-7.5-all.zip]

I update distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip`

But it always failed. I need to run `gradle sonar` second time to build the task and it passed.

I checked the gradle version running using `gradle --status` and it shows that gradle *7.4-rc.1* is running, not *7.5* as defined in `gradle-wrapper.properties`.

[image: gradle --status shows gradle 7.4-rc.1 running instead of 7.5]

Currently I have no serious issue with this, just need to run `gradle sonar` twice to scan my project. But I want to know why change in `gradle-wrapper.properties` does not take effect when run `gradle` command.

I'm using *Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2*

Comment: have you tried running AGP assistant?

Comment: @solitude I tried but it does not work.

Comment: try running ./gradlew --version on your terminal then try running ./gradlew sonar on your android studio terminal

Comment: @solitude gradle --version result is 7.4-rc-1

Comment: if it is a Github repo, try cloning again and do the update step by step using AGP Assistant only. I also encounter issues like that but AGP assistant always fix the problem without manual editing. See if it works.

Comment: @solitude I clone project but gradle version still 7.4-rc-1. Thank you for your suggestion.